# Windows 7 "Guest mode" implementation?

Tags: user-profiles, persistent

Windows 7 beta had a feature called "**Guest Mode**", based on **SteadyState** or **PC Safeguard** that was available for Win XP and Vista. SteadyState was perfect! But for some reason discontinued support for Windows 7.
How can I implement something similar in Windows 7? Closest I can think of is parental control, I could limit what the users can do, but I cannot prevent them from altering files. At the same time I want them to be able to use the files, and the programs needed will need read-write access.
**How can I make the changes a user makes to the user's profile and files temporary per login session?**
Any help appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ef232619-7600-4768-b111-f60ba13862ea) is how to do it using tools available from Microsoft.

I haven't downloaded or read it yet, so I can't comment on how useful it is.